# Android/Phonegap app APK too big for Google Play. How to implement extensions?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-play

I have finally been able to get my phonegap/dreamweaver app build to work for Android and have a working APK file.
however, the final APK is going to be much larger than 50mb (google plays limit) due to the fact it has 700 images in it.
i realize that I could host them on a server, but I want the app to be completely usable when not online or connected to a network.

In order to get under the limit, I need to use extension files. 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

has anyone been successful doing this with an app that was made using phonegapp/dreamweaver and finished in eclipse?

If yes, would appreciate guidance on the best way to do it....
Would i zip my www folder and make that the extension file? how do I link it properly in eclipse?

Noel

Comment: While researching the same topic I found following tutorial: http://www.nsbasic.com/app/tutorials/TT12.htm I haven't tried it yet but maybe it can help you.